# Raid software (mdadm) has unexpected size

Tags: debian, mdadm

I have a server with 4 hard drives at 4 To (3.7 TiB).

I first created a partition on each drive with type "fd" (Linux Raid Autodetect).

Then, I configured a RAID 10 using mdadm with the following command :

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10  --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

With 4 drives at 4 To each, I was expecting a Raid 10 to be at 8 To, but it looks like the Raid is around 4To as displayed here:

```
$> mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Jun  1 12:38:03 2020
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 4294700032 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2147350016 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Jun  2 07:36:34 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : storage.infra.improvmx.com:0  (local to host storage.infra.improvmx.com)
              UUID : 2c13947e:0003bac1:cf35004e:26ec0d9f
            Events : 20932

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       33        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd1
```

And this is the details for /dev/sda:

```
$> mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2c13947e:0003bac1:cf35004e:26ec0d9f
           Name : storage.infra.improvmx.com:0  (local to host storage.infra.improvmx.com)
  Creation Time : Mon Jun  1 12:38:03 2020
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 4294701055 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294700032 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294700032 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ddcf2074:533602a9:d1f96dfa:1680da8e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jun  2 07:37:39 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : c5230c1c - correct
         Events : 20931

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

/dev/sdb1:

```
$> mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2c13947e:0003bac1:cf35004e:26ec0d9f
           Name : storage.infra.improvmx.com:0  (local to host storage.infra.improvmx.com)
  Creation Time : Mon Jun  1 12:38:03 2020
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 4294701055 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294700032 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294700032 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : e8a6dc07:e88c8b49:29515d45:de406876

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jun  2 07:38:10 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 2be551fc - correct
         Events : 20932

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

/dev/sdc1

```
$> mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2c13947e:0003bac1:cf35004e:26ec0d9f
           Name : storage.infra.improvmx.com:0  (local to host storage.infra.improvmx.com)
  Creation Time : Mon Jun  1 12:38:03 2020
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 4294701055 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294700032 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294700032 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : a9801a8e:62d9f8e6:2c94777f:150d9837

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jun  2 07:38:49 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 4ada879a - correct
         Events : 20932

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

And /dev/sdd1 :

```
$> mdadm --examine /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2c13947e:0003bac1:cf35004e:26ec0d9f
           Name : storage.infra.improvmx.com:0  (local to host storage.infra.improvmx.com)
  Creation Time : Mon Jun  1 12:38:03 2020
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 4294701055 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294700032 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294700032 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4c67f6e4:5563c402:4f4bd249:157f8aa4

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jun  2 07:39:21 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : f4cf2172 - correct
         Events : 20931

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I tried using e2fsck then resizefs, with no luck. I also rebooted and it didn't change anything.

Do you have any idea what happened? What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What size are each of the partitions? I wonder if the disks gave been partitioned with MBR which tops out at about 2tb.

Comment: I kept the default when using fdisk (primary, first sector, last, etc). But I noticed that the state of sdb1 and sdd1 is "Clean" whereas the state of sda1 and sdc1 are "Active". I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the size of your partitions.

You indicated you used fdisk. fdisk only supports MBR, which is limited to a bit over 2tb.

The solution is to blow your RAID10 away, repartition the disks using something like gdisk or gparted.  Alternatively, if you are not booting from any of these disks you can simply use the while disk rather then a partition, eg /dev/sda not /dev/sda**1**

Comment: Is there a way to do that without blowing the raid? It' currently in use :/

Comment: Apologies for this comment, but to be truthful - I don't believe so at your level of skill.   Depending on the configuration, an expert may be able to degrade the array, repartition 2 of the disks, rebuild the array, degrade the other 2 disks, expand the disks, rebuild array, expand array.  This is likely much trickier and riskier then it sounds especially if you are booting off the RAID.  You are likely better off rebuilding.   After all, you do have backups, don't you... RAID IS NOT BACKUP!

Comment: lol, it's not for backup, and it's not used to boot on it, it for storage with lots of IO writes ;)

Comment: Well, in the end I id that. Removed the array, created a new one without disk partitioning. Now I'm at 7.9To, which is better :) Thanks!

Comment: Corrigendum: fdisk has supported GPT since util-linux 2.23 released in April 2013.